# Commons Net FTP fails when transferring a directory, but works single file

Tags: java, upload, ftp

I have a Commons Net FTP file problem.  I have an application which can transfer either a single file or a directory to a remote host, depending on what the user clicked on in a JTree.  When I am transferring a particular directory, the transfer always fails on the same file, with a 'Software caused connection abort: socket write error'.  When I select the same file and transfer it as a single file, it works fine.  The relevant code for the directory transfer is:

```
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os,8*1024);
if (filelen > 500){
buffer = new byte[(int) (filelen/100)];
}else {
buffer = new byte[(int) filelen];
}
int len; 
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is,8*1024);
int ba = bis.available();
while ((len = bis.read(buffer)) != -1 && ba != 0)  
{
//os.write(buffer, 0, len);
System.out.println(ftp.getReplyString());
System.out.println("len is "+len);
System.out.println("ba is "+ba);
System.out.println("first two bytes are "+buffer[0]+buffer[1]);
System.out.println("last byte is "+buffer[buffer.length-1]);
System.out.println("buffer length is "+buffer.length);
int rc = ftp.getReplyCode();
if (rc == 550){
hftstatus.setText("Copy Error encountered, check log.");
return;
}
bos.write(buffer,0, len);
bos.flush();
System.out.println(ftp.getReplyString());
ba = bis.available();
if (filelen > 500){
if (len > 0){
left -=len;
totleft -=len;
   }
}else{
left=0;
}
if (ba < buffer.length){
buffer = new byte[ba];
}
double ip = (left*100)/filelen;
int percomp =  (int) (100-ip);
double ap = (totleft*100)/totlength;
int perallcomp = (int) (100-ap);
hftcurrfileprog.setValue(percomp);
hftallfileprog.setValue(perallcomp);
hftstatus.setText("Copying file "+f+" "+percomp+" percent completed.");
                }
```

and the relevant code for a single file is:

```
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os,8*1024);
    if (filelen > 500){
    buffer = new byte[(int) (filelen/100)];
    }else {
    buffer = new byte[(int) filelen];
    }
    int len;
    while ((len = bis.read(buffer)) != -1)  
    {
        bos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        int rc = ftp.getReplyCode();
        if (rc == 550){hftstatus.setText("Copy Error encountered, check log.");}
        bos.flush();
        bytestran += len;
        if (filelen > 100){
        left = left-(filelen/100);
        }else{
            left=0;
        }
        double ip = (left*100)/filelen;
        int percomp =  (int) (100-ip);
        hftcurrfileprog.setValue(percomp);
        hftallfileprog.setValue(percomp);
        if (bytestran == filelen){break;}
        }
        String outm = ftp.getReplyString();
        System.out.println(outm);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        bis.close();
        os.close();
        is.close();
        ftp.completePendingCommand();
        System.out.println(ftp.getReplyString());
        totleft = 0;
        double ip = (left*100)/filelen;
        int percomp =  (int) (100-ip);
        int perallcomp = 100;
        hftcurrfileprog.setValue(percomp);
        hftallfileprog.setValue(perallcomp);
        hftstatus.setText("file "+fnode+" copied to directory "+remoteDirPath+nwd);
```

Any thoughts or clues would be much appreciated.   I many hits somewhat close to this, but none where the only difference is in directory or single file transfer.   Thank you for your help.

Comment: You really should fix your formatting here. Please check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I fixed my formatting.  Thank you for pointing me to the directions on how to do this.